# redirect http to https only for 1 domain not all

Tags: http, https, dns, effect

Hi my domain name is https://null24.net and it opens only with `https / non-www`

So when the user types null24.net/post1 it redirects to null24.net/post1 with https / non-www

My new addone domain is tutsload.com and without https

But I don't want the changes that I have done on null24.net to affect the tutsload.com and I wanna null24.net keep going process without giving effect on tutsload.com. So tutsload.com does not redirect to Null24.net

Here is null24.net htacces. Please tell me how I should change it

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.null24.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://null24.net/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://null24.net/$1 [L,R=301]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```